# web service and its configuration file

Tags: tomcat, web-services

I implemented one service and it has several configuration item, such as data type, next node, blablabla. What I want to do is to deploy the service and configuration file into tomcat within one .aar.

However, if I jar the service and configuration file into the aar. The service can't read the file though the file is there in the same directory.

Even I put the file into tomcat_home\bin, the service fails to read the file.

I know it should work. Can anybody give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of service ? Is this an app ? not sure what you mean

Comment: @Romain, it is a web service, for instance, you can view it through http://localhost:8080/axis2/services. The configuration file here I talk is called web service supporting file.

Comment: http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_2/userguide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this it is very comprehensive and should help you out
http://www.ericsson.com/developer/developerszonedown/downloads/docs/open_development_tips/jwsdp.pdf

Comment: It is a good article, but I have to use axis2 to deploy rather than JWSDP.